# Servicio AngularJS me devuelve Undefined en return!

Tags: angularjs

He intentado todas las maneras posible de cambiar el orden del código, pero pasa lo mismo una y otra vez, me estoy frustrando, quisiera saber porque devuelve undefined para no volver a toparme con este problema, He realizado las pruebas para saber que la siguiente función no regresa vacía, pero aun así lo hace. Demuestro mi código a continuación:
A continuación defino la aplicación:

```
var app = angular.module('sonidoambiental', ['ngRoute']).
        config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'inicio.html', abstract: true, controller: "InicioController"}).
                when('/listado', {templateUrl: 'listado.html', controller: "ListadoController"})./*
      when('/agregar', {templateUrl: 'plantillas/agregar.html', controller: ControladorAgregar}).*/
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
```

El servicio que me devuelve undefinited es el siguiente:

```
app.factory('comunicacion', function() {
        return {        
        obtenerstring: function(pregunta){            
            var retorna;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/json/' + encodeURI(pregunta),
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'get',
                success: function(datos) {
                    /* Si todo ha ido bien mostramos una alerta con el contenido */
                    if (typeof datos.error !== 'undefined' && datos.error === false) {
                        console.log(datos.mensaje);
                        retorna= datos.mensaje;                        
                        //alert("Mensaje recibido: " + datos.mensaje);
                    } else {
                        retorna = null;                        
                    }
                }
            });
            return retorna;
        }
        }        
    });
```

Y la llamo de la siguiente forma:
app.controller("InicioController",['$scope', 'comunicacion',function ($scope, $interval, comunicacion) {
    $scope.primerinicio=function(){
        if (comunicacion.obtenerstring('sinusuarios') === ' ') {
            titulodeformulario = "No hay usuario creado por favor ingrese los datos correspondientes";
                        crearusuario = true;
                        botoningresar = "Crear usuario";
                        $scope.titulodeformulario = titulodeformulario;
                        $scope.botoningresar = botoningresar;
                        $scope.crearusuario = crearusuario;
                        $scope.$apply();
        }

Pues si alguien me aclara este panorama seria de muy grata ayuda, En la parte que dice Console.log(datos.mensaje); me devuelve el valor real y no undefinited, por tanto aseguro que no es un problema de función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema radica en la implementación del factory.

```
app.factory('comunicacion', function() {
    return {        
    obtenerstring: function(pregunta){            
        var retorna;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/json/' + encodeURI(pregunta),
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'get',
            success: function(datos) {
                /* Si todo ha ido bien mostramos una alerta con el contenido */
                if (typeof datos.error !== 'undefined' && datos.error === false) {
                    console.log(datos.mensaje);
                    retorna= datos.mensaje;                        
                    //alert("Mensaje recibido: " + datos.mensaje);
                } else {
                    retorna = null;                        
                }
            }
        });
        return retorna;
    }
    }        
});
```

Tienes una declaración de variable

```
var retorna;
```

Luego una invocación a un metodo jQuery asincrono.

```
$.ajax(...)
```

Para finalmente retornar la variable declarada anteriormente

```
return retorna;
```

Lo anterior solo funcionaria si la invocación fuera sincrona. Pero mas importante aun, deberías usar componentes angular como el servicio `$http` y retornar una promesa como resultado.

Docs del servicio:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta